# React not consistently returning the "name" attirbute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've been having some problems with my react application in which I have two `buttons`  with `name` attributes `order-accepted` and `order-declined` and both of these buttons have the `onClick` listener which triggers a function `confirmOrder` when one of those buttons are clicked which in turn emits a socket event according to the `name` attribute of the `button` which was clicked, But for some reason when I click any of the two buttons sometimes react returns the actual name attribute of the button and sometimes it just returns `undefined` can anyone please help me with this, Below I've pasted the code snippet if anyone could point out what might be wrong with it. P.S - I've also tried using `event.target.getAttribute('name')` but it doesn't solve the problem either.

```
//these are those two buttons that I mentioned
<div className="buttons">
  <button  className="accept-decline-button accept" name="order-accepted" onClick={e => {this.confirmOrder(e)}}> <strong>Accept</strong> </button>   
  <button  className="accept-decline-button decline" name="order-declined" onClick={e => {this.confirmOrder(e)}}><strong>Decline</strong></button>
</div>
```

And below is the method that gets triggered when one of them are clicked

```
confirmOrder = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const orderNumber = this.props.selectedOrder.orderNumber;

    console.log('Event name is',name);
    if(name === 'order-accepted') {
        console.log('Accepted');
        socket.emit('order confirmation',orderNumber , true);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Declined');
        socket.emit('order confirmation', orderNumber, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.target` is the element the event was targeted at, which can be a *descendant* of the one it was hooked on, in this case your `strong` element, which has no `name` attribute. So when the click is on a space either side of the `strong` element, you see the name, but when it's on the `strong` element, you don't. To get the element you hooked the event on, use `currentTarget`: `const { name } = event.currentTarget;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much that fixed it!